# How to change SIM card PIN code in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, pin, sim

On a Windows 8.1 notebook with integrated SIM card slot (not a Windows phone), how do I change the SIM card's PIN code?

I tried to find a screen that allows me to do that. I cannot put the SIM in my phone as that requires a micro-SIM card.

Comment: There is likely to be a number of ways this MAY have been made possible. Please state the exact model of the notebook you have - best is to read it from the label on the device (backside/bottom) and type it exactly as is.

Answer (score 4):

Open right charm bar (Ctrl + C) -> Settings -> More PC Settings -> Network

Inside your broadband connection you have options in order to manage the PIN Code